# Checkbox (model) dosn't change value when checked

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Ive made some checkboxes in a View. The checkboxes is implemented via the ViewModel with bool properties. I'm currently trying to change a query in the controller to "date" or "month" depending if the checkbox has been checked. However in the Controller it always jumps the the "else statement" even if "Month" has been checked. Month is always False.

I suspect the JavaScript code might be wrong.

**This User Interface:**

[image]

In my Controller method i try to do the following:

**Controller:**

```
 var request = GoogleAnalyticsService.Data.Ga.Get("ga:59380223", start, end, "ga:visitors");



    var request = GoogleAnalyticsService.Data.Ga.Get("ga:59380223", start, end, "ga:visitors");


            if (model.Month)
            {

                request.Dimensions = "ga:month";
                request.Sort = "-ga:month";

            }

            else
            {
                request.Dimensions = "ga:date";
                request.Sort = "-ga:date";
            }

            request.MaxResults = 10000;

            Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData d = request.Execute();
```

In The view ive implemented my Viewmodel and tried writing some javascript checking if what checkbox have ´been checked and if to return true or false:

**View:**

```
    <table class="adminContent">
             <tr>
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.StartDate): 
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.EndDate):
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="data" colspan="2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { id = "Day" }) // -- Checkbox Date
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
            </td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
             <tr>
        <td class="data" colspan="2">
                @Html.CheckBox("chkMonth", new { @onclick = "updatemyhidden(this)" }) // -- Checkbox Month
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Month, new { id = "Month" })
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Month)           
        </td>
    </tr>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.GAStatisticsId ):
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.DropDownList("GAStatisticsId", Model.AvailableGAStatistics)
                    <input type="button" id="GAStatisticsReport-Submit" class="t-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.Search")" />
            </tr>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#GAStatisticsReport-Submit").click(function () {

        if ($("select[name='GAStatisticsId'] option:selected").text() == "Visitors Report")
            drawChartVisitors()

        if ($("select[name='GAStatisticsId'] option:selected").text() == "Orders Report")
            drawChartOrders()

        if ($("select[name='GAStatisticsId'] option:selected").text() == "Conversion Report")
            drawConversion()

        function updatemyhidden(chkbox) {
            $("#Month").val(chkbox.checked);

        }

    })
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["treemap"] });
    function drawChartVisitors() {
        $.get('/GAStatistics/GetVisitors', {
            StartDate: $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.StartDate)').val(),
            EndDate: $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.EndDate)').val(),



        },
            function (data) {
                var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                tdata.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                tdata.addColumn('number', 'Visitors');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


                    if ($("#Month").is(":checked")) {


                        var dateStr = data[i].Date.substr(0, 4);
                    }



                    else {

                        var dateStr = data[i].Date.substr(0, 4) + "-" + data[i].Date.substr(4, 2) + "-" + data[i].Date.substr(6, 2);
                    }


                    tdata.addRow([new Date(dateStr), parseInt(data[i].Visitors)]);
                }
```

The if-statements in the controller dosnt seem to operate depending on what i select in the view.

Note: im not using httpPost/get as the data is loaded with Google Charts and i don't want the whole page to re-aload each time a new request is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Is because you set bool field on the month so it will rendered as `true/false` for your checkbox. You have a look at the rendered HTML for the `month` checkbox., and no matter you checked or not the data still send back to server as `true/false` depend what been set when rendering the page. This value will never change.

So i suggest you either add one more property in your viewmodel to keep try `check/unchecked` state and in the view rendered it as hidden field and update this hidden field whenever checkbox is `ticked/unticked`.

Or the `month` field render as hidden field and add one more checkbox in the page to update the `month` field when checkbox is `checked/unchecked`

Let say we use 2nd approach, the code will look something like this, (I did not test the code below). I hope this helps:

```
@Html.CheckBox("chkMonth", new { @onclick = "updatemyhidden(this)" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Month)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatemyhidden(chkbox) {
        $("#Month").val(chkbox.checked);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Okej. Do you mean like "bool MonthChecked = true" and "bool Month Unchecked = False". That would result in 2 check boxes in the view - "model.MonthChecked" and "model.MonthUnchecked". Is this what you mean? And which one should be hidden? thx

Comment: - Thanks i also updated my post trying to scale down the code and make Month work first. However month dosn't seem to get validated and in the Controller it alsways jumps to the else statement and add date to the request. I've moved the validation code to the button.click so it validates after the button has been clicked, thereafter i still have the if/else stamenets checking if the checkbox has been selected and return month or date string-format but it wont work. I must have done something wrong?

Comment: Are you saying the hidden field (month) still not updated? Could you use fiddler to check what value been send back to server? or you can check from firebug or google chrome console to make sure it's updated on hidden field before hit submit button